# Risk of dropping users in postgres

Tags: postgresql, security

Is there any risk in DROPPING users in postgres?
We have bunch of users in our database that no longer work at the company.
I was wondering what (if any) risk there was in dropping those users?

Answer (score 0):

The only risk is that you might drop a user that you still need.

Other than that, PostgreSQL tracks dependencies between users and other objects and won't let you drop users that have permissions or own objects in the database.